# Firebase set() promise stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do a simple write to the Firebase Database like so:

```html
return app.register( email, password ).then( f => {
  return app.login( email, password )
} ).then( f => {
  return app.currentUser()
} ).then( user => {
  return app.firebase.db().ref( `users/${user.uid}` ).set( {color: 'red'} )
} ).then( f => {
  console.log( "This never triggers" )
} )
```

Where `app.register` is:

```
( firebase, email, password ) => firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
```

Where `app.login` is:

```
( firebase, email, password ) => firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
```

And `app.currentUser` is:

```
firebase => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        firebase.auth( ).onAuthStateChanged( user => {
            user ? resolve( user ) : reject( user )
        } )
    } )
}
```

And `app.firebase` is an initialised Firebase reference.

I am getting no errors, but the `set()` never resolves.

I'm very much stuck, any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever try to `catch` errors in your chain?

Comment: Yes. But since the .set() seems to be stuck on pending the .catch() doesn't trigger either. I'm running this in a mocha testing environment and have tried timeouts of up to 60 seconds to see what would happen. No errors, nothing.

Comment: @Mentor Seems you are using ` `(backticks)` in your `.ref...` call, I hope it will be normal quotes right?

Comment: No, they are backtics. Im using babel to transpile in webpack. `path/${thing}` is equal to 'path/' + thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

When using partial imports like:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import auth from 'firebase/auth'
import db form 'firebase/database'
```

Firebase silently fails some elements when not run in a browser (I was using Mocha).

Solution (which sucks) is to import the full package:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```